# VHDL state transitions based on if statements - works on board but doesn't work in simulator

Tags: vhdl, simulation, state

I hate to ask *yet* another question on here but apparently I'm really useless with simulators :(.

Basically, I have a traffic light controller that is made up of a bunch of different states and a few timers running for different lengths of time. When the system enters a state, it activates a timer and there is an if statement that watches the timer output and points the system to the next state when the timer output value is 1.

This all works fine on the board, but when I simulate it the count ticks to '1' but the next state isn't selected. This can be seen, here:

[image: Simplified simulation]

I've tried to boil the code down into the essentials below, but if you need more context (and are feeling far more generous than I deserve) then the full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/RqrzK71R).

Initialisation:

```
entity trafficlightcontroller is
  port
  (
    clk       : in  std_logic;
    reset     : in  std_logic;
     ambulance : in std_logic;
     smr          : in  std_logic;
     sml          : in  std_logic;
     ssr          : in  std_logic;
    rlmr          : out std_logic;
     almr         : out std_logic;
     glmr         : out std_logic;
     rlsr         : out std_logic;
     alsr         : out std_logic;
     glsr         : out std_logic
  );
end entity;

architecture rtl of trafficlightcontroller is

  -- Build an enumerated type for the state machine
  -- r=red;a=amber;g=green;c=car waiting;m=main road;s=side road
     type state_type is (rmgs, rmas, rmrs, amrs, gmrs, gmrcs, ramrs, rmacs, rmrcs, ramrcs, rmras, rmrs2);

  -- Signals to hold the states
     signal present_state, next_state : state_type;
      signal divclk, reset2, reset2b, reset3, reset3b, reset10, reset20, reset20b, count2, count2b, count3, count3b, count10, count20, count20b: std_logic;

      component timer is
            generic (
                trigger_cnt:    natural := 20
            );
            port (
                 clk:        in      std_logic;
                 reset:      in      std_logic;
                 count:      buffer  std_logic
            );
      end component timer;

      component clockdivider
            port(clkin : in std_logic;
         dividedclk : out std_logic
            );
        end component clockdivider;
      begin

      timer2 : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 2) port map(divclk,reset2,count2);
      timer2b : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 2) port map(divclk,reset2b,count2b);
      timer3 : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 3) port map(divclk,reset3,count3);
      timer3b : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 3) port map(divclk,reset3b,count3b);
      timer10 : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 10) port map(divclk,reset10,count10);
      timer20 : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 20) port map(divclk,reset20,count20);
      timer20b : timer generic map (trigger_cnt => 20) port map(divclk,reset20b,count20b);
      divider : clockdivider port map(clk, divclk);
```

The beginning of the states (including the state shown in the simulation):

```
 case present_state is

      --Red light main; green side road
    when rmgs=>
         reset2 <= '0';
         reset2b <= '0';
         reset3 <= '0';
         reset3b <= '0';
         reset20 <= '0';
         reset20b <= '0';
         rlmr <= '1';
         almr <= '0';
        glmr <= '0';
        rlsr <= '0';
         alsr <= '0';
         glsr <= '1';
         reset10 <= '1';
         --if count is complete then move to next state
         if ( count10='1' ) THEN
            next_state <= rmas;
         --otherwise, return to current state
         else
            next_state <= rmgs;
         end if;
```

Clock process:

```
--Every clock tick, the next state is selected as the present state.
  state_clocked: process(clk)
  begin
     if ( rising_edge( clk ) ) THEN
        present_state <= next_state;
     end if;
end process state_clocked;
```

The line I entered into the simulator to initialise the clock:

```
force clk 0 0ns, 1 10 ns -repeat 20ns
```

Answer (score 1):

Your next_state process is missing lots of signals in the sensitivity list.  This will probably fix it.  VHDL-2008 allows you to use the keyword "all" instead of signal names.  If your synthesis tool supports this, it might be worth using.

The rest are suggestions:

With a two process statemachine, reset logic is most often captured in the state_clocked process.  And hence, look more like this:

```
state_clocked: process(clk)
begin
  if ( rising_edge( clk ) ) THEN
    if Reset = '0' then 
      present_state <= rmrs;
    else
      present_state <= next_state;
    end if ;
  end if;
end process state_clocked;
```

You can shorten your code significantly if you use a default assignment to assign the "off" value to all signal outputs of the next_state process:

```
next_state_proc : process (present_state, ssr, ambulance, Count10, Count3, ... )
begin
  -- default assignments
  reset2 <= '0';
  reset2b <= '0';
  reset3 <= '0';
  reset3b <='0';
  reset10 <= '0';
  reset20 <= '0';
  reset20b <= '0';
  rlmr <= '1';
  almr <= '0';
  glmr <= '0';
  rlsr <= '1';
  alsr <= '0';
  glsr <= '0';
  next_state <= present_state ;  -- optional

  -- Statemachine code starts here
  -- Only do assignments that are different from the default.

  if ssr = '0' then
    -- Do you change the values from the defaults here?
    -- with the defaults, it is not necessary to do any assignments here, however, 
    -- without the defaults these outputs would have latches on them.
    case present_state is
      when gmrs =>  next_state <= gmrcs;
      when rmas =>  next_state <= rmacs;
      ...
    end case ; 

  elsif ambulance = '0' then 
    -- Do you change the values from the defaults here?
    -- with the defaults, it is not necessary to do any assignments here, however, 
    -- without the defaults these outputs would have latches on them.
    case present_state is
      when gmrs | ramrs | ramrcs =>  next_state <= amrs;
      -- when rmas =>  ???
      when rmgs | rmras =>  next_state <= rmas;
      ...
    end case ; 

  else
    -- main statemachine
    case present_state is
      when rmgs=>
        -- Only drive outputs that are different from the defaults here.
        rlsr <= '0';
        glsr <= '1';
        reset10 <= '1';
        --if count is complete then move to next state
        if ( count10='1' ) THEN
              next_state <= rmas;
        --otherwise, return to current state
        else
              next_state <= rmgs;
        end if;
      when rmas=>
        . . .
    end case ;
```

Comment: shouldn't that be present_state as a target under reset in the present_state register?  (You show next_state, it creates two drivers in two different processes.)

Comment: @DavidKoontz.  Thanks.  I have updated the code.  You are welcome to edit yourself if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The reset for the present_state register isn't strictly needed for simulation, but should be there for synthesis.

```
state_clocked: 
    process(reset,clk)
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            present_state <= rmrs;
        elsif  rising_edge( clk )  THEN
            present_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process;
```

(Jim beat me to it).

```
  process (present_state, reset, ssr, ambulance, count2, count2b, 
           count3, count3b, count10, count20, count20b)
```

Adding the process sensitivity elements (and using reset):

[image: tb_rfc with cross traffic]

(I added a bit more to it.  A lot of your design appears to be working to a good extent.)

And think about using a test bench, it would allow automated testing by generating inputs on ambulance, smr, sml and ssr.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_tfc is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_tfc is
    signal clk:        std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:      std_logic;
    signal ambulance:  std_logic := '1';
    signal smr:        std_logic := '1';
    signal sml:        std_logic := '1';
    signal ssr:        std_logic := '1';
    signal rlmr:       std_logic;
    signal almr:       std_logic;
    signal glmr:       std_logic;
    signal rlsr:       std_logic;
    signal alsr:       std_logic;
    signal glsr:       std_logic;
begin 

DUT:  
    entity work.trafficlightcontroller
    port map (   
          clk,
          reset,
          ambulance,
          smr,
          sml,
          ssr,
          rlmr, -- out
          almr, -- out
          glmr, -- out
          rlsr, -- out
          alsr, -- out
          glsr  -- out
    );

CLOCK:
    process

    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 1280 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULUS:
    process 
    begin
        reset <= '0'; -- 
        wait for 20 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 1020 ns;
        ssr <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```